# how can i import Data from MYSQL table in to SQL Server Compact table (.sdf) using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```vb
Dim con1 As New MySqlConnection("server=")
Dim con2 As New SqlCeconnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Barcodedatabase.sdf;Password=leonado-abg;Persist Security Info=True")
'Create the data adapter with a SelectCommand using the first connection.
 Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Items", con1)

 'Add the InsertCommand with the second connection.
 da.InsertCommand = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Items ", con2)

 'Add the insert parameters.
 da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "ID")
 da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Name")

 'Keep the records ina state where they can be inserted into the destination table.
 da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False

 Dim dt As New DataTable

 'Get the data from the source database.
 da.Fill(dt)

 'Save the data to the destination database.
 da.Update(dt)
```

Comment: Don't use a MySql provider for MS Sql Server. `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` and then use `Using con2 As New SqlConnection("Your sql server connection string")`

Comment: How did OleDb get into this?

Comment: Sorry. There seems to be a Nuget package System.Data.SqlServerCE_unofficial that would be better suited. I am afraid the Compact edition is very different and won't work with the regular Sql Server provider.

Comment: If your ID field is an identity field in Sql Server CE you may have a problem. In Sql Server your would add SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Coffees OFF

Comment: ok how can i fix it

Comment: how can i insert from mysql table in to .sdf  table  using vb.net

Comment: OK thank you .............

Comment: A question that is nothing but a title and code is unacceptable. You need to write a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. If the code you have doesn't do as expected, you need to describe EXACTLY where and how its behaviour differs from your expectation.